# Beginner Sockets with .NET/C# : Request desktop icons

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, client-server

I'm developing a little application which will connect to a remote machine, and return to the client a list of the remote's desktop icons.

I currently have this functionality working for local desktop icons.

In theory, I would assume I'd have to give the remote server the code I used to get the icons locally, and then send a command to the server to trigger it to run said method. Then I would return it's return value back to the client for further processing / display.

What sort of objects / architectures should I be looking at to accomplish such a thing? Would I have a switch on the server to go through various different command possibilities? Couldn't this get out of hand in very large applications? How would I send a "Shortcut" object as a byte stream to the client and then re-create the "Shortcut" on the client?

Comment: It sounds like you need to synchronise desktop shortcuts between machines (I assume the files/programs the shortcuts point at have already been synchronised)? If so, can you not use an off-the-shelf sync package instead of coding something from scratch?

Comment: This is just an example I'm toying with. The goal is for me to be able to double click on the shortcuts returned by the server, and have the associated program open on the server machine, not the client. 

1. Request
2. Show user Shortcuts
3. Double click and Send Message
4. Parse Message. 
5. Launch Program.

Comment: ok, how about using off-the-shelf remote control software instead? The RDP protocol used by Windows Remote Desktop (among others) may already do some of what you need.

Comment: RDP causes the current session to be signed off once a remote session signs on, which isn't practical for my purposes. I have looked into both RDP and Windows Sharing API.

Comment: My question is more what sort of architecture should one use in .NET/C# to work with a client/server type application, that can send different types of data other than just strings.

Comment: And how to attach custom events to things like "Message Received"? so if I receive a message like "Desktop_Shortcuts" it would fire the "requestDesktopShortcuts" event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing remote desktop functionality is not necessary the easiest exercise to learn networking.

To start it may be easier to implement console application redirection or even simple [telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) client (you can enable telnet on some versions of Windows to play with without writing server side portion).

If want to learn about how remote desktop could be implemented consider reading about Unix implementation of it [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System).

As for graphic UI support - read on RDP, or read articles about FogCreek's CoPilot (which implements almost exactly what you want) - [CoPilot technical info](https://www.copilot.com/tech/), or start with list [Comparison of remote desktop software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) to find more info.